# How to recognize elements/shapes from a sketch path?

Tags: image-processing, pattern-matching, cad

I have an image, it could be a small sketch like the one on[image: this image], or preferably a screenshot of a DWG file, or any other CAD format.

I want to be able to decompose the path into components that I have already predetermined.

The components would be something like a 2x2 right angle, a 1x3 130degre angle and then getting the dimension of the rest of the linear segments.

I would first have to assign a dimension to a segment so that I can extrapolate the dimensions of the rest of the sketch (scale).

I'm seeking advice to find the best way and tools to solve this problem.

Comment: What's a *"2x2 right angle"* please? 2 what by 2 what? Inches? Centimetres?

Comment: Units it doesn't really matter the whole path is going to be the same unit, you could choose cm for this case.